# How to refresh token from a windows service?

Tags: onedrive, live-sdk

Is it possible to refresh a token if the application does not have access to a browser control or http context?  I have a WinForm that logs a user in and gets consent, it then passes the token to a windows service so files can be uploaded to OneDrive.  When the token expires, it seems all the methods for refreshing a token require a callback URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you've requested the `wl.offline_access` scope and you're using the Authorization Code grant flow in OAuth 2.0. Once the user has logged in through OAuth, you'll receive an `access_token` which is valid for 1 hour, and a `refresh_token`, which is valid for a long time.

Each time your service needs to do work on the user's behalf, you can redeem the `refresh_token` for a new `access_token` and `refresh_token`, and then use the `access_token` to do work. Make sure you save the new `refresh_token` you get back as well, to make sure that you extend the expiration.

This way you can have a service that performs actions on behalf of the user for a long time, without needing the user to sign in again. However, it is possible for the `refresh_token` to expire or become invalid, so you will need to handle situations where you are unable to redeem the `refresh_token`.